# Object does not match target type reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm building a small framework for my WPF application. I have the following view model:

```
public class MyViewModel : ICanHandle<MyCommand, CanHandleMyCommand> {}
```

In the background when my ExtendedEventAggregator publishes a command of type `MyCommand`, it will look up all subscribers of this command, and find the implemented interface to see if it can handle this.

```
public ExecuteStrategy(MethodInfo command, Type canExecuteType)
{
   Command = command;
   CanExecuteType = canExecuteType;
   CanExecute = CanExecuteType.GetMethod("CanExecute");
}

public void Execute(object message)
{
   CanExecute.Invoke(CanExecuteType, new[] { message });
}
```

Running the Execute method will result in an exception saying

> Object does not match target type.

I thought the CanExecuteType was the type associated with this method?

What am I missing here?

Comment: `CanExecuteType` is a `Type` object, `Invoke` requires an _instance of CanExecuteType_.

Comment: BTW, an event aggregator is not intended for command processing. Furthermore, an event aggregator shouldn't care about subscribers/publishers. Forcing an event aggregator to look up for particular subscribers is a design flaw.